# How to efficiently make this color wheel?

Tags: plotting, graphics

The best approach I can find is the following:

```
ClearAll[color];
color[a_,b_]:=Piecewise[{{Hue[1/2-Arg[a+b I]/(2\[Pi]),1,1],0.8<Norm[{a,b}]<1.0},{White,True}}];
Graphics[Flatten[Table[{color[a,b],Rectangle[{a,b},{a+0.05,b+0.05}]},{a,-1,1,0.05},{b,-1,1,0.05}]]]
```

[image: color wheel graphics]

This approach is very inefficient if I use enough rectangles to make the circles look smooth. It seems there must be a better way using ParametricPlot, RegionPlot, ComplexPlot, ColorFunction, etc. Can you find a better way?

Comment: Don't have time to work out a solution now, but I'd suggest you look into Texture. See, for example the filled curve example here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider, for instance:

```
RegionPlot[
 Element[{x, y}, Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.8, 1}]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[1/2 - Arg[#1 + #2 I]/(2 Pi)] &)]
```

[image]

Without `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` `x` and `y` are scaled to $[0, 1]$... which can be a bit surprising if you don't remember this functionality. :)

As a side note, `ComplexPlot` *can* do the same, but interestingly enough `RegionFunction` doesn't really work particularly well with it.

---

**EDIT**:

Inspired by @Syed, you can also accomplish the same with the following:

```
ComplexRegionPlot[0.8 < Abs[z] < 1, {z, 1},
 Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None,
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[-#4] &)]
```

It is, by the way, the same as this:

```
ComplexRegionPlot[0.8 < Abs[z] < 1, {z, 1},
 Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[1/2 - #4/(2 Pi)] &)]
```

Oftentimes I find the way colour function scaling works in Mma regarding coordinates more confusing than useful; `#4` is clearly the argument of `z`, but with scaling it runs from $0$ to $1$ - but it's not that it would have been just divided by $2\pi$, no, it again depends on the actual plotted region...

Comment: that's very nice!

Answer (score 5):

```
ComplexRegionPlot[0.75 < Abs[z] < 1
 , {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}
 , BoundaryStyle -> None
 , ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &)
 , Frame -> False
 ]
```

OR

```
DensityPlot[Arg[x + I y]
 , {x, y} ∈ Annulus[{0, 0}, {0.75, 1}]
 , Exclusions -> None
 , ColorFunction -> Hue
 , ImageSize -> 300
 , PlotPoints -> 50
 , MaxRecursion -> 3
 , Frame -> False
 ]
```

OR

```
PieChart[ConstantArray[1, 360]
 , SectorOrigin -> {{π, 1}, 3}
 , ChartStyle -> {
   EdgeForm[None]
   , (Hue[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/360])}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, `ComplexRegionPlot` behaves better than `ComplexPlot` with `RegionFunction`!

Comment: BTW, you can replace `{z, -1 - I, 1 + I}` with `{z, 1}`.

Comment: I saw the colors on `0` and $\pi$ and missed their circular progression. This can be fixed using: `-Arg[x + I y]` in the first solution, `ColorFunction -> (Hue[-#4] &)` as pointed out by @kirma and using `SectorOrigin -> {{\[Pi], -1}, 3}` in the PieChart solution.

Comment: @ Syed, Very good, but the graphic is upside down.

Comment: @TedErsek, please see above your comment for the resolution.